# How to fix this code so that it shuffles letters and has no affect on first letter and last letter, punctuation

Tags: arrays, go, slice, shuffle, letter

I'm dealing with go/golang, trying to write code that takes a string and seed. It should return a shuffled string where the 1st and last letters in the word, punctuation and numbers are untouched.

Example:

> my name is Nikki. My number is 333

should be

> my nmae is Nkiki. My nebumr is 333

I'm very new to goland/go. Have tried to do it with `rand.Shuffle`:

```
   func splitText(text string) []string {
    re := regexp.MustCompile("[A-Za-z0-9']+|[':;?().,!\\ ]")
    return re.FindAllString(text, -1)}


    func scramble(text string, seed int64) string {

    rand.Seed(seed)
    split := splitText(text)

    for i := range split {
        e := split[i]

        r := []byte(e)

        for i := 0; i < len(r); i++ {
            l := len(r) - 1
            if i == 0 {
                return string(r[0])
            }
            if i == l {
                return string(r[l])
            }

            if i > 0 || i < l {
                n := rand.Intn(l)
                x := r[i]
                r[i] = r[n]
                r[n] = x

            }

            if (r[i] >= 32 && r[i] <= 62) || (r[i] >= 91 && r[i] <= 96) {
                return string(r[i])
            }
        }

    }
    return text

}

func main() {

    v := ("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.")
    scramble(v, 100)
    fmt.Println(scramble(v, 100))

}
```

But this returns only one letter and only if `remoe f==0` or `f==l`, it doesn't hop to the next word.

Comment: In the nested for-loop, you  have an `if i==0` condition, which is always true the first time that loop runs, so it returns without executing the rest of the code. Inner for-loop index `i` is shadowing the outer loop `i`, so maybe that's the source of your confusion.

Comment: but how to fix so that i it will print and shuffle?

Comment: With the way you're doing it, you'll lose word boundaries and punctuation. So I suggest you change your algorithm. One way you can do this is to convert your string to a []rune, and iterate the elements. As you're iterating, find out word boundaries, shuffle the bytes in between using rand.Shuffle, and convert the resulting []rune to string and return.

Comment: can you explain with some code example?

Comment: I can't write the code for you, but the algorithm I described need to keep a state variable that tells whether you're in a word or not. When you're not in a word if you see a letter (unicode.IsLetter), you change the state variable, and continue as long as you see letters. When you see a non-letter, that gives you the end of the word. Then, you can shuffle the runes between word start+1:word end-1, and continue.